# Quick way to remove duplicate objects in a List in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.7

I have a list of MyClass objects which is made like so:

```
# The class is MyClass(string_a: str = None, string_b: str = None) 
test_list: List[MyClass] = []
test_clist.append(MyClass("hello", "world"))
test_clist.append(MyClass("hello", ""))
test_clist.append(MyClass("hello", "world"))
test_clist.append(MyClass(None, "world")
```

I want the end result to only have the 3rd append removed:

```
# Remove test_clist.append(MyClass("hello", "world"))
```

This is just a sample and the list of objects can have nothing in the list or n. Is there a way to remove them quickly or a better way like how to quickly tell if it already exists before appending?

Comment: try `list(set(test_clist))` set cannot have duplicates and are often used to remove them

Comment: Can set be used with non-primitive types like in my case?

Comment: set() in your example will compare the objects references not values

Comment: Your type must be [`hashable`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable), that means you need to implement `__hash__(self)` and `__eq__(self, other)` methods

Comment: @cdub unfortunately not out of the box

Comment: I have only been in python for a month, how do you do eq and hash?

Comment: @cdub my answer provided an easy way to implement `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods in order to use `set`

Comment: thanks i upvoted and marked it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your objects are of primitive types, you can use `set`

```
list(set(test_clist))
```

and if not, like your case then you have 2 solutions

**1- Implement `__hash__()` & `__eq__()`**

You have to implement `__hash__()` & `__eq__` in your class in order to use `set()` to remove the duplicates

see below example

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MyClass({self.x} - {self.y})"

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ != other.__class__:
            return NotImplemented

        return (
            self.x == other.x and
            self.y == other.y
        )

l = []

l.append(MyClass('hello', 'world'))
l.append(MyClass('hello', 'world'))
l.append(MyClass('', 'world'))
l.append(MyClass(None, 'world'))

print(list(set(l)))
```

Since you have more than one key that you want to use in comparing, `__hash__()` uses a key tuple.

`__repr__()` just for representing the class's object as a string.

**2- Use 3rd Party Package**

check out a package called [toolz](https://pypi.org/project/toolz/)

then use `unique()` method to remove the duplicates by passing a key

```
toolz.unique(test_list, key=lambda x: x.your_attribute)
```

In your case, you have more than one attribute, so you can combine them into one, for example by creating a concatenated property for them then pass it to `toolz.unique()` as your key, or just concatenate them on the fly like below

```
toolz.unique(test_list, key=lambda x: x.first_attribute + x.second_attribute)
```

Comment: `__eq__` returning `False` for unrecognized types is usually wrong behavior. Standard practice if an operator overload doesn't recognize the other operand is to return `NotImplemented`, to give the other operand a chance to handle the operation. (If both objects return `NotImplemented` from `__eq__`, `==` returns `False`.)